# Java installation in folder with accents (diacritics)

Tags: java

I have a problem with java installed in folder with accents. Java is unable to start itself in this folder but when I run my project in Java I'm able to handle these special symbols. Test is with "zulu11.37.19-ca-fx-jre11.0.6-win_i686". Here is an example:

```
c:\test-ěščřž\bin>java.exe -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library:
```

Folder without accents:

```
c:\test-escrz\bin>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.37+19-CA (build 11.0.6+10-LTS)
OpenJDK Server VM Zulu11.37+19-CA (build 11.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode, emulated-client)
```

Any ideas please? Except running java from folder without accents. 
Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Johannes Kuhn! The problem is related to Java version [JDK-8242283](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242283). For me 11.0.6 and newer doesn't work in folders with accents. 11.0.5 works, but that folder must have atleast one regular letter in name. The rest can be accents letter (funny..). If not than the message is different thatn before but still doesn't work. 
So 11.0.5 is kind of compromise between using new Java11 and fix for accents.

```
c:\ěšštčřžý\bin>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.35+15-CA (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
OpenJDK Server VM Zulu11.35+15-CA (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode, emulated-client)

c:\ěšščřžý\bin>java -version
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

Comment: That is a case i've never seen before. Good to be aware of this. Thanks for sharing, hope you find an answer.

Comment: Saw a bug recently about that. Should be fixed in the next java version. Here we go: [JDK-8242283](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242283)

Comment: @user2014512 Please undelete your deleted answer and add the updated details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Johannes Kuhn! The problem is related to Java version JDK-8242283. For me 11.0.6 and newer doesn't work in folders with accents. 11.0.5 works, but that folder must have atleast one regular letter in name. The rest can be accents letter (funny..). If not than the message is different thatn before but still doesn't work. So 11.0.5 is kind of compromise between using new Java11 and fix for accents.

```
c:\ěšštčřžý\bin>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.35+15-CA (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
OpenJDK Server VM Zulu11.35+15-CA (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode, emulated-client)

c:\ěšščřžý\bin>java -version
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```